# PKBarcodeFormatQR for dark mode (iOS 13)

Tags: ios13, wallet, passkit, ios-darkmode

I have an implementation of PassKit for my application's loyalty card. After introducing dark mode I have managed to change the background colors but the QR code's background color is still white.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWoCH.png

Is there a type of barcode that will invert the QR code colors? Currently I am using **PKBarcodeFormatQR**

Thanks

Comment: This wouldn't be possible because if you inverted the colors they would not scan correctly

Comment: Andy McSherry is right, if you invert your qr code then most of the scanners will have a hard time reading your code and it will be useless then.